# Why does wrap_content to width in TextView holds the full width?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple `TextView` in a `LinearLayout`. 
When I set the TextView width to `wrap_content` it gets flexible with the content but as I set the orientation of my layout to `vertical` then the text gets the full width of the screen.

**I have set the background color for both layout and textview, so I can see the actual occupying space of my text**

I have read the difference between wrap_content and match_parent but in my case, it doesn't actually do what it is supposed to do.

[image: Here's an image of how it looks]

Here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#fe4236"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


<TextView
    android:text="Hi there!"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="#ccddff"
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hello Rose, welcome to SO! Can you post a screenshot of how it looks in both cases and how you'd want it to look?

Comment: Hey Martin. I just added.

Comment: _as I set the orientation of my layout to vertical then the text gets the full width of the screen_ -> this doesn't make sense; you need to post the entire Layout and/or what your results are because with the provided information, there's not enough information to determine what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

Apologies if I sounded like I was *chastising* your or if it sounded like a personal attack on my original Answer; I didn't have the full picture and assumed you were looking for a solution to the problem.

What I truly wanted to articulate was that the snippet of XML you posted *doesn't* produce the same output in my environment (and it *shouldn't* to the best of my knowledge); when I looked at it, it looked *fine* even before attempting to run it, so it made me *frown* at the possibility which also let me to believe *you were doing something else that I wasn't aware of*, hence why I asked for more info.

Now that we know you're using an online visualizer... let me tell you that I've never seen it before, but for context, the Android Studio visualizer looks like this:

[image: Android Studio designer]

The *only modification* I made to your snippet is to add the *missing* XML header:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

at the top of the file (Udacity visualizer gives an error if you add it).

So in summary, what I tried to say in my original answer, is that there's nothing you need to do here, for your assumption that the `wrap_content` in the `TextView` should be enough for the text to *wrap* its content, is **correct**.

**Udacity is wrong** and it's not correctly rendering a Vertical Linear Layout with wrapping children on the horizontal axis.

Good luck with your training!

<sub>*For what is worth, (and only to make sure you see where I come from), if you would have posted the Udacity thing when you first posted this question, I would have been able to save you the trouble and potentially frustrating experience of having to read my original answer.*</sub>

### ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW, NO LONGER RELEVANT.

I'm not sure where/how are you seeing this, but I think you need to understand how the Layout engine works on Android first.

#### What's going on

I pasted your code in my Android Studio (3.4.1) and here's what I see:

[image: Your Layout]

It doesn't matter if it's `vertical` or `horizontal` for there's plenty of space to put both in either orientation.

#### What can you do?

If you feel like doing it using ConstraintLayout (I would) then this is how you'd achieve the same result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                                             
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#fe4236"
  >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        android:text="Hi there!"
        android:background="#ccddff"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

(Not posting a screenshot, but trust me it looks the same).

Comment: thanks, but I'm not looking to get this fixed only. I'm looking for a proper explanation that why it doesn't give me the same output with my code.

Comment: No problem, what I'm trying to say is that _in the code you posted_ there's nothing to fix, because it's correct code; my suspicion, is that you didn't post the _entire_ code. Is that XML the entirety of the file or just the piece that doesn't behave as expected? Does this happen at runtime? What did you try? I would gladly help you understanding what's going on, but without the rest of the picture, I cannot tell you much more. Your XML is valid, at least in Android Studio 3.x. What else can you share (code, pics, etc.) that may help us understand?

Comment: I just started learning android and it is the full piece of code which I'm practicing. This code doesn't give me the expected output, maybe because I'm using an online  XML visualizer [link ] (https://labs.udacity.com/android-visualizer/#/android/linear-layout-weight)

Comment: @Rose See updated answer. (long story short: your online visualizer is **wrong**)